# Apostrophe in html source

Tags: php, html, facebook, encoding, character-encoding

when I create a news that has an apostrophe in title (example here: http://www.gamempire.it/news/project-cars-in-arrivo-su-playstation-4-ed-xbox-one-ma-c-e-anche-una-brutta-notizia-131554), looking at the html source i can see an

```
&#039;
```

When I share this news on Facebook, it display the code `&#039;`, and this is not so good.

How can I fix this? Do I have to convert the string in something else with php?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source-Code already contents the meta-tag for sharing on Facebook with this special char encoding, but with an "amp;" to much:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Project CARS in arrivo su Playstation 4 ed Xbox One, ma c&amp;#039;è anche una brutta notizia - Gamempire">
```

In

```
& amp; #39;
```

you have to remove the amp; ;)

So, first you have to Check why and where your Script is transorming the ´-Char.
Is this an CMS you use?